# Tradutor em javascript

Tags: javascript

Tem um jeito mais facil de fazer esse codigo? sem if else.

```js
<script>
  var traduções = ["1", "2"]
  
  var escrita = (window.prompt())
  
  if(traduções[0] === escrita){

document.write("a")

  } if(traduções[1] === escrita){

document.write("b")
   
  };
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem algumas maneiras diferentes que você pode fazer isso:

**Primeira maneira: Operadores ternários**

```javascript
var escrita = (window.prompt())
  
document.write(escrita === '1' ? 'a' : 'b')
```

**Segunda maneira: Switch case**

```js
var escrita = (window.prompt())

switch(escrita) {
  case '1':
    document.write('a')
    break
  case '2':
    document.write('b')
    break
}
```

**Terceira maneira: Array de strings**

```js
var strings = ["a", "b"]
  
var escrita = (window.prompt())

document.write(strings[+escrita - 1])
```

Os três exemplos apresentados são básicos mas espero que consigam te ajudar.